# "Fatal: Needed a single revision" appears when bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

I git pull a project to my local side (MacOS), and I need to perform bundle install before running rails server. However, during this process, when one of the Fetchings was executed, the following error occurred.

I have tried to add branch 'main', but it didn't work.

```
Fetching http://github.com/RubyMoney/eu_central_bank.git

fatal: Needed a single revision

Revision master does not exist in the repository http://github.com/RubyMoney/eu_central_bank.git. Maybe you misspelled it?
```

Comment: Find the version of `eu_central_bank` in the Gemfile.lock. Check if it is available in the github repo or not. It might have been archived or deleted.

Comment: I see the following, I am not sure if it is available: `specs:
    eu_central_bank (1.4.0)
      money (~> 6.13)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8.1)`

Comment: I have tried ```git fetch``` and then perform a ```bundle install``` (a necessary step before ```rails server``` ). There is no error message when executing git fetch, but bundle install still stops at the same error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in an internal project. We did a workaround so I can't test, but I just traced some bundler source code. The code for `ref:`, `tag:`, and `branch:` is all the same. They are treated as synonyms.

This failed:

```
gem 'my-gem', :git => "https://my-server/my-gem.git", :tag => 'v0.1.0'
```

The error looked like this...

```
Fetching https://my-server/my-gem.git
fatal: Needed a single revision
Git error: command `git rev-parse --verify v0.1.0` in directory
```

We discovered that by default branches are pulled by the `git clone`, but not all tags. Tags that are not on a branch don't always get pulled. To workaround we just created a branch that contained the tag in question.

In the future it might work if you specify the reference like this...

```
gem 'my-gem', :git => "https://my-server/my-gem.git", :tag => 'refs/tags/v0.1.0'
```

If you look at the code I link to in github, you see that triggers the value `extra_ref` to be set, which triggers an additional git fetch to get that ref specifically.

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/6a655a698e952f897d0d014fc11bae4b608528ce/bundler/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb#L88-L104

It does a two step process. First it does something like this... (The ./foo is a target directory. It can be anything.)

```
git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- https://my-server/my-gem.git ./foo
```

Then it does this...

```
git --git-dir=./foo fetch --force --quiet --tags -- https://my-server/my-gem.git refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/v0.1.0:refs/tags/v0.1.0
```

which will explicitly get the tag in question.

This second step is done whenever the reference begins with `ref/`.